# Automatic update failure?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a laptop - Toshiba Satellite 130-11u with Windows 7 Home Premium, purchased on summer 2010.

During my work it was network error ( likely wi-fi - because I was connected via Wi-Fi) . 
I tried to reboot 
But during reboot I got message

> `Don't disonnect your computer, installing update 4 from 14`

The computer still stuck for several hours .
How the issue can be resolved - I need at least to reboot normally my laptop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you try the infamous and completely (most of the time) useless Repair (Restore might work if you have it on):

- Try booting into safe mode delete the downloaded/fragmented peices of update or
- Boot into safe mode with Networking and do the update or
- start in normal mode or
- try last known good configuration.

Hope that helps... other wise like above!

Comment: Thanks - after selecting last good configuration - it seems work

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine has once stopped the updating process by powering off the computer. Afterwards the computer wasn't able to boot anymore. He had to use an installation CD to go the rescue mode and reset the system to a restore point. Afterwards he was able to install the updates normally. Thus you should have an installation CD at hand. If you need to go to the boot menu you can do that by holding down F8 during the boot process.

So turn off the computer and use a system restore point, where the updates are not installed yet. Afterwards install them again.

Comment: Thanks - after selecting last good configuration - it seems work